# How to append and delete data in the middle of a text file, shifting the remaining file content using java code?

Tags: java, file-io

I am using `RandomAccessFile` but `writeBytes()` overwrites the
existing content Mostly i want to implement this without using any new
temporary file at least methods name few clues or techniques will do.

Comment: use `seek()` to move to a byte location. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: You need another data structure than a text file for this to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert text after a particular line of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473303/how-to-insert-text-after-a-particular-line-of-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert without the use of any temporary file, you'll have to find a way to read in and shift all subsequent lines down by one when you insert a new line.
The sequential storage of lines of text poses the same kind of issues that the use of a standard array (vs. a LinkedList) does:   You can't just unhook a pointer, plop in some text, and then hook up the pointer to next item to point to a subsequent line in the file.  You have to perform the entire shift.

So I'd guess that you'd want to go to end of file, shift it down by a line, then move up each line and perform the same shift until you hit the position at which you want to insert the new line, at which point, you'll have cleared a space for it.

This seems very performance inefficient.

Hopefully someone knows of a better way, but this would be my approach, were a temporary file not an option.

(Alternately, you could also always just read the whole thing into a StringBuffer if it were small enough, peform the insert within that, and then write the file back out from scratch, but I imagine that you've considered that option already.)